# MS Access VBA SQL query debugging select case

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013, select-case

In MS Access 2013 VBA I get a syntax error in this SQL-string:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO [man_year] ( man_year_val, year_int, main_research_area, organisation, man_year_source ) SELECT KU.[2007], '2007' AS Expr1, " _
& "select case right(left(KU.man_year_source;6);2) like 'Hu' 3 case right(left(KU.man_year_source;6);2) like 'Sa' 1 case right(left(KU.man_year_source;6);2) like 'Te' 2 case right(left(KU.man_year_source;6);2) like 'Su' 4 case right(left(KU.man_year_source;6);2) like 'Ud' 5 AS Expr2, " _
& "4 AS Expr3, " _
& "select switch" _
& "(left(KU.man_year_source;3) like '1. '; 1;" _
& "left(KU.man_year_source;3) like '1.1'; 4;" _
& "left(KU.man_year_source;3) like '1.2'; 5;" _
& "left(KU.man_year_source;3) like '1.3'; 6;" _
& "left(KU.man_year_source;3) like '1.4'; 7;" _
& "left(KU.man_year_source;3) like '1.5'; 8;" _
& "left(KU.man_year_source;3) like '1.6'; 9;" _
& "left(KU.man_year_source;3) like '2. '; 2;" _
& "left(KU.man_year_source;3) like '2.1'; 47;" _
& "left(KU.man_year_source;3) like '2.2'; 48;" _
& "left(KU.man_year_source;3) like '2.3'; 49;" _
& "left(KU.man_year_source;3) like '2.4'; 50;" _
& "left(KU.man_year_source;3) like '2.5'; 51;" _
& "left(KU.man_year_source;3) like '2.6'; 52;" _
& "left(KU.man_year_source;3) like '3. '; 3;" _
& "left(KU.man_year_source;3) like '3.1'; 53;" _
& "left(KU.man_year_source;3) like '3.2'; 54;" _
& "left(KU.man_year_source;3) like '3.3'; 55;" _
& "left(KU.man_year_source;3) like '3.4'; 56;" _
& "left(KU.man_year_source;3) like '3.5'; 57;" _
& "left(KU.man_year_source;3) like '3.6'; 58) from KU;"
```

I get the error in the CASE-part, but that might be because it hasn't reached the SWITCH-part yet. :-) Can anyone please help, I cannot find the error.

Best pmelch

Comment: from what i can make out (please format yuor post) yuo have several `SELECT` clauses following one-another. That is not going to work. You do not need `SELECT` before each `CASE`

Comment: Access does not have a `case` AFAIK

Comment: Even if it does or would, I have never known a case that works like this...

Comment: Is SO really the first port of call now? Do people not even try to search their own documentation or examples before coming here?

Comment: @Ben - what do you know about what I have searched?

Comment: Only that it is very little. `Case` doesn't look like that when it is supported, so you haven't looked that up. access doesn't support `case` so you haven't looked that up either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least two issues with your SQL statement:

First, Access SQL does not support the `CASE` keyword. If you were thinking of the `CASE ... WHEN` construct in [T-SQL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) (Microsoft SQL Server) then the equivalent in Access SQL is the `Switch()` function (ref: [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/switch-function-HA001228918.aspx)). You can think of the `Switch()` function as doing

```
Switch(when1, then1, when2, then2, ...)
```

Second, as far as I know Access SQL only supports period (`.`) as the decimal symbol and comma (`,`) as the list separator, even if the Regional Settings on your machine specify other values (e.g., comma (`,`) as the decimal symbol and semi-colon (`;`) as the list separator). In other words, I'm fairly certain that

```
left(KU.man_year_source;3)
```

will never work; you'll need to use

```
left(KU.man_year_source,3)
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks Gord for your answer! It works for me now. When there are many different errors involved it may be difficult to do debugging. I found sites that say CASE will work in Access SQL and others that say CASE won't work, so for me it was trial and error.

Comment: And then I found that my long list of when/then in the switch statement won't work. It is better to have a table with these conditions and the refer to that table. Anyhow - thnx for a non-arrogant answer Gord.